# Do not display a user id in the jquery datatable, but it available

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatable

wanted to know if it is possible to display some data from a user in a datatable, but when taking the data in a row, take the user id (but not display this id in the table)

My table:

```
<table  id="mitabla" class ="display">

    <thead>
        <tr><th>Apellido</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Nombre de Usuario</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="body">
        <?php
        include "bd/administrador/usuarios/abm.php";
        $consulta = listarUsuarios();

        while ($registro = $consulta->fetch()) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . utf8_encode($registro[Apellido]) . "</td><td>" . utf8_encode($registro[Nombre]) . "</td><td>" . utf8_encode($registro[NombreUsuario]) . "</td></tr>";

        }

        ?>
    </tbody>   
    <tfoot>
        <tr><th>Apellido</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Nombre de Usuario</th></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

At $consulta I have the user id, but I will not show it on the table.

When showing data from the selected row, I want to show the selected user id in the table
(JavaScript)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id;

    oTable = $('#mitabla').dataTable();

    oTable.$('tr').click( function () {
        var data = oTable.fnGetData( this );
        id=data;
        alert("" + id[0]);
    });
```

thank you very much !

Comment: Why can't you just remove the ID from the array server side and pass it through with row id's or some made up counter if you really need it?

Comment: Thanks, I solved it. I have the id in my table, but when hidden just fit a datatable that column. That way I do not show the user id, but if you have available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I have the id in my table, but when hidden just fit a datatable that column. That way I do not show the user id, but if you have available.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                   var id;

                    oTable = $('#mitabla').dataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }
        ]
    } );

                    oTable.$('tr').click( function () {
                    var data = oTable.fnGetData( this );
                    id=data;
                    alert("" + id[0]);


  } );
```

And when I build the table I also added the userid

```
<table  id="mitabla" class ="display">

     <thead>
         <tr><th>Id</th><th>Apellido</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Nombre de Usuario</th></tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="body">
<?php
include "bd/administrador/usuarios/abm.php";
$consulta = listarUsuarios();

        while ($registro = $consulta->fetch()) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . utf8_encode($registro[idUsuario]) . "</td><td>" . utf8_encode($registro[Apellido]) . "</td><td>" . utf8_encode($registro[Nombre]) . "</td><td>" . utf8_encode($registro[NombreUsuario]) . "</td></tr>";

            }

?>
     </tbody>   
     <tfoot>
    <tr><th>Id</th><th>Apellido</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Nombre de Usuario</th></tr>
     </tfoot>
 </table>
```